# Creating Seamless nested scroll rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

I am attempting to create a series of window sized divs with inner divs of variable sizes > window size. The catch is it needs to scroll as if the divs where not nested.

***In short I want THIS:***

```
css{
     block{ height:100wh; }
     innerBlockSmall{ height:100wh; }
     innerBlockLarge{ height:200wh; }
}


<div class="block">
    <div class="innerBlockLarge"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="innerBlockSmall"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbuh8psd/

***to act just like THIS***

```
css{
     innerBlockSmall{ height:100wh; }
     innerBlockLarge{ height:200wh; }
}

    <div class="innerBlockLarge"></div>
    <div class="innerBlockSmall"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t6zrvo7u/1/

Unfortunately scroll "Focus" is triggered by `hover`ing over the scrollable element. In this case it is an undesirable behavior.

There are 2 possible solutions that I am currently aware of.

1. Manually Assigning scroll "Focus" via javascript.  *(Optimal)*
2. Completely overwriting default HTML scrolling javascript, for
   example the library ISCROLL5.
   *(ok, if the performance hit is small)*

Unfortunately after looking through developer.mozilla's HTML5 documentation I have not run across any way to "Focus" scrolling to an element via javascript.

As for option 2 : ISCROLL5 has had an undesirable performance hit with over ~15-20 scrolling divs.

I am hoping I am missing something here, any solutions, fixes, or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Removing `overflow: auto` from `.sbRemover` disables the scrolling on hover.

Comment: Sadly this behavior is not quite that simple. Removing `overflow: auto` causes the element not to scroll at all. The desired behavior is the nested  `<div class="block">`scrolls to overflow to the `<body>` scroll as if they where not nested. See the 2nd JS fiddle for the desired behavior

Comment: @DigitalDouble Thanks for the fast reply though. Any and all suggestions are helpful.

Comment: I did not understand perfectly, my english is not so good :) . The div must not scroll? Instead overflow:auto use overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have *no* idea why you would wish to do this, but the only way I can think of achieving the effect you want is along the lines of recreating the scrollbar, the good news however is that this needs not come at the cost of losing your native like experience.

Sadly I can't remember the project I wrote this code for, though one way to achieve this is to make yourself a scrollbar component. This scrollbar component would indeed provide a fake scrollbar, but provide a native like interface. So, how do you do this?

1. You determine the width of the scrollbar by taking the difference between an element with and without `overflow: scroll`. Let this be `scrollWidth`
2. You create a `<div>` with `overflow: auto` of width `scrollWidth` and `position: fixed` this in place on the right side of the body. Let the `scrollTop` property be `scrollPosition`.
3. Inside the element you add another `<div>` with width `0` (this at least works in Chrome, check whether other browsers treat this differently) and let height be `documentLength`.
4. Now, you can fully control the scrollbar by setting `documentLength` and `scrollPosition` any way you wish to. In your case you would set `documentLength` as the combined scrollHeights of each element and `scrollPosition` based on the relative `scrollTop`'s in those nodes.

A very basic demonstration of the concept (not the implementation) can be found in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cdnob9r/) (note the `width` of the scrollbar is fixed to `20px` in this case and there is no dynamic code whatsoever).

Answer (score 2):

This solution allows scrolling over entire document while keeping the possibility of scrolling each nested div with mouse. I hope I understood you correctly.

This is just a concept, it does not prevent nested elements from scrolling along with window. But it can be improved.

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName('sbRemover') )
.forEach(function (div) {
    var scroll = 0,
        mousedown = false,
        mouseBtnHandler = function (e) {
            mousedown = e.type == 'mousedown';
        }
    
    div.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        // Change of div's scrollTop. Negative when scrolling down
        var diff = scroll - e.target.scrollTop;
        // Save new scroll value to be able to compare with it later
        scroll = e.target.scrollTop;
        // Do nothing when div is scrolled by dragging the scrollbar
        if (!mousedown) {
            // Scroll the window to the same amount of pixels the div was scrolled
            window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset - diff);
        }
    });
    div.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseBtnHandler);
    div.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseBtnHandler);
});
```

```css
body, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.block{
    position: relative;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 100;
}
.sbRemover{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-right:15px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.largeContent{
    height:225vh;
}
.smallContent{
    height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="simpleCanvas">
  <div class="block" style="background-color: blue">
    <div class="sbRemover">
      <div id="ok" class="largeContent" style="background-image: url('http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile-art/images/grey-repeating-background-8.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="sbRemover">
      <div class="largeContent" style="background-image: url('http://a1star.com/images/star--background-seamless-repeating9.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background-color: green">
    <div class="sbRemover">
      <div class="smallContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background-color: blue">
    <div class="sbRemover">
      <div class="smallContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="sbRemover">
      <div class="largeContent" style="background-image: url('http://people.stfx.ca/x2011/x2011ane/info102/assignment1/11500341-abstract-colorful-repeating-background.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block" style="background-color: green">
    <div class="sbRemover">
      <div class="smallContent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```